# How to send Facebook Push notifications to Android Device?

Tags: android, facebook, push-notification

I have integrated facebook push notifications in my application (Android). I have only seen option in dashboard that we can create/run campaigns to send the notifications to the device. Do we have an option to send simple notifications without creating campaigns? Does Facebook provide an option like urban airship ?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is facebook push notification?

Comment: @TimCastelijns : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/04/12/facebook-analytics-for-apps-adds-push-notifications-deeper-insights/

Comment: what notifications would you send exactly, without a campaign? what is the exact use case?

Comment: @luschn Like title and body I supposed to send like announcements to the users. Example: Hey, here is the new video available. Please checkout

Comment: to which users would you send this, without a campaign? i don´t get it, sorry.

Comment: @luschn : For all users, when new video is added in the server.

Comment: i don´t think that´s what facebook notifications are meant for, to be honest...better use email or something else.

Comment: you can try this to verify push for single device.(Goto section 5) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/push-campaigns/quickstart#5--verify-your-push-credentials

Comment: @BharathKumarBachina : it is for testing whether compaigns working or not.